# Lectures on wormholes

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, resource-recommendations, education, wormholes

I am currently writing a review as a thesis project and I must cover black holes and wormholes, static and stationary. For black holes I found this [lecture](https://luth.obspm.fr/%7Eluthier/gourgoulhon/bh16/bholes.pdf) where black holes are approached from a more mathematical point of view. However, for wormholes I didn't really find much material (except for this [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-020-8409-5) but I would like to know more). Could you recommend sources that cover wormholes from a more mathematical point of view but without neglecting the physical concepts?

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03809 and references therein

Comment: Visser's book "Lorentzian Wormholes"